# Wordpress shortcodes working on WP editor but not on PHP files

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm using Memberium to create a membership site.
To set the different levels of memberships I need to use shortcodes.
I need to write these shortcodes in the template files but they only works on Wordpress editor.

I'm trying this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[memb_has_membership memberships=normal]');?>

<h1>HELLO</h1>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[/memb_has_membership]');?>
```

Also, I have been tried without the echo, and writing only HTML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried combining everything into one call?

```
<?php 

$str = "[memb_has_membership memberships=normal]<h1>HELLO</h1>[/memb_has_membership]";
echo do_shortcode($str);

?>
```

A cleaner way would be to use the plugin's PHP functions directly in your code.

The shortcode's function is `member_hasMembership()` ([Documentation](https://memberium.com/memb_hasmembership/))

```
<?php if(memb_hasMembership( ‘Gold’ )): ?>

    <h1>HELLO</h1>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Shortcodes are not meant to be used in a PHP script, so it gets messy very fast. You should use your plugin's PHP functions directly instead. See here for the same functionnality https://memberium.com/memb_hasmembership/